# Hosting PostGIS database on a personal Google Drive?

Tags: postgis, google-drive

We are a not for profit charity trying to manage/minimise costs for a GIS project being used to characterize freshwater resources and share the results.

We currently have a "migrator" which pulls data from an Epicollect5 cloud database into a Google hosted PostGIS environment.   From there the data is manipulated via an API for use in QGIS (mapping/interpretation) and in a WebMap (data graphing).  This workflow is costing money.
Is there an alternative to PostGIS on Google, we can use DynamoDB for part of the workflow but this does not support geospatial data interrogation.

Can we use a personal Google Drive for postGIS hosting, or are there alternatives for what we want to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon RDS has a 'free tier' that allows you to operate a PostgreSQL w/ PostGIS database on a small server without cost. Depending on the number of users and amount of usage, you might be able to get away with this:

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/

Otherwise, Google Drive is really just for files, not hosting a database server. You could possibly host a SQLite database in this environment...

Comment: is there an ssue with the Amazon free tier RDS requiring an “internet gateway” (in order to connect with the Lambda functions we use for our migrator and API) the internet gateway is quite pricey?

Comment: @jamssiwater I wouldn't think so... it's still Epicollect5 -> PostgreSQL... it comes down to security settings, etc. which are easily configured on the Amazon RDS side.

Comment: OK we will check it out.  Thank you!

Comment: @jamssiwater good stuff!